# Jasmine spies callThrough and callFake

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a scenario whereby I want to call `done()` on a `beforeEach` after a callback has been invoked.

I tried to do this as follows :

```
spyOn(scope, 'onAdmin').and.callThrough().and.callFake(function(){done()})
```

But I'm not sure I get the right behaviour. Essentially what I want to achieve is to be able to call `done()` after each callback is done doing what it does.

**UPDATE: workaround solution**

```
scope.onAdminBackup = scope.onAdmin;
spyOn(scope, 'onAdmin').and.callFake(function(admin)  {

 scope.onAdminBackup();
 done() ;

})
```

Comment: Is there any other solution except this workaround?

Comment: Does this code result in an infinite loop as `scope.onAdminBackup()` calls `scope.onAdmin` which is faked to call `scope.onAdminBackup()` and so on

Answer (score 3):

I have never chained these kinds of functions together cuz in my mind they seem to do the opposite. You are saying when I call this method -onAdmin - in the scope call it as normal. Which is what the callThrough method jasmine provides for us does.

But then you are chaining along a callFake method as well so then you say but dont actually call it call this fake function instead - very conflicting.

If you want to call spy on the method onAdmin and instead of it being fired you want it to do something else - something mocked - then use the .and.callFake(fn). Also take into account like @stefan above said - dont invoke the function - callFake is simply wanting a function as a parameter it will take care of calling it itself.

This might be more along the lines of what you are looking for, if not show us some more code.

```
spyOn(scope, 'onAdmin')and.callFake(done)
```

Comment: I understand that it's actually conflicting. I guess the solution would be to do what I put as my last comment in Stefans answer.

Comment: Interesting test approach! I am curious to see what you are testing with such an approach!? But yes I think thats the only way you are gonna get what you want - and what you want I dont know. Isnt is possible to simple call the original function in the callFake method? As an object is pass-by-reference anyways you are in fact calling the same thing.

Comment: I actually tried that but it didn't work. It errors with a stack error because it keeps on getting invoked as it's being spied /watched.

Answer (score 2):

you are calling done right-away when you write done()
try passing in done as a value:

```
spyOn(scope, 'onAdmin').and.callThrough().and.callFake(done)
```

Comment: Someone edited my question. I had function ()  { done()} in callFake. Still doesn't work.

Comment: The only workaround I've found is the following: make a backup of my function before it is spied on. Only callFake with my backup function and then afterwards done. Seems a bit of a hack  though

Comment: yeah looks cleaner. I would go with the workaround, easier to read too. But why do you need to call the function anyway? do your tests rely on it being called?

Comment: Yeap they do! Or I want them to be I guess :)  those callbacks are some of the ways I know I have data back from the server and some variables are assigned in them and would like to check against them as opposed to faking them.

Comment: It's better to test with fake data than having a server running for the tests, you can do e2e testing with protractor to test if the integration with the real app works!

Comment: Otherwise you won't know if it's your server or your angular app which is failing a test.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around way to do this. Jasmine has a method called addSpyStategy where you can add a custom strategy like callThrough or callFake. It would look something like this:

```
jasmine.addSpyStrategy('callThroughAndThen', (spy, fn) => {
  return function() {
    spy.and.callThrough();
    setTimeout(() => fn(...arguments), 0);
  }
});
```

the timeout makes sure the real function finishes before executing the custom function. Then for your spy, you can do this:

```
const spy = spyOn(scope, 'onAdmin')
 spy.and.callThroughAndThen(spy, () => {
  // your custom callback
  done();
});
```

note: make sure to put custom strategy in a beforeEach block